# Solr-lucene query format errror

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm getting an error when using the format in a Solr (v6.4) query: 
   `boost=max(0.85,query(field:*))` to boost all docs with field `field`.
But I'm sure about the format that should be used in such cases. Here's the error originating from:
`https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionQParser.java: 298`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to find documents with a specific field present is `field:[* TO *]`.

Comment: Thanks :-) I simply need to define `field` first as well.